# Regex match between the 4th and the 5th "_"

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

In SQL (Bigquery).

I want to use regex_extract function and extract the expression between the 4th and 5th "_"

Example:
From this expression:

```
Bubble_ALLTIERS_30-65+_M_2%Payers100-500_AEO7D_29_1_EN
```

I want to extract the phrase `2%Payers100-500`

Thank you.

Comment: Show what you have tried as a [mcve]. For reference there is https://regex101.com/ You may also have to [edit] this question and explain the limits and requirements. Are there always the same number of underscores? How would a human pick out the part you want? If you can't describe the general pattern to a human, you can't to a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and looks to me an easiest way to do such extraction

```
SPLIT(phrase , '_')[SAFE_OFFSET(4)]
```

You can test it as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Bubble_ALLTIERS_30-65+_M_2%Payers100-500_AEO7D_29_1_EN' phrase 
)
SELECT SPLIT(phrase , '_')[SAFE_OFFSET(4)] word 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row word     
1   2%Payers100-500
```

Another option would be

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(phrase, r'[^_]+')[SAFE_OFFSET(4)]
```

Comment: Good idea. Thank you.

Comment: consider voting up the answer if you liked it and it helped

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^(?:[^_]*_){4}([^_]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4o6wnX/1/).